# S3 image resizing in IE 10 using ng-croppie library

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, image-upload, request-headers

I'm using ng-croppie (https://github.com/allenRoyston/ngCroppie) library to upload and resize the images and its working fine all browsers, when the images are stored in my server.

When the images are getting from S3 bucket, It saved empty image only in IE 10. 
Other browsers, it works fine.

My bucket's cors configurations are,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

and there is no bucket policy.

Any help or advice will be really appreciate.

Thanks for the help!